# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) - Python

Tags: python, json

Below is my code, i am using to test jasmin for sending sms. When i a send a message through jamsin, i get the error

Comment: Shouldn't `removeNonAscii` do something?

Comment: i guess it should but i am not able to tell why it is giving me that error. @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any `phone` to `get` from `data`.